# Tagging category of custom component in Joomla 3.2

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have set up categories for my custom component in Joomla 3.2 using the instructions here: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_categories and looking at the com_weblinks component (since a few things were changed between 2.5 and 3.2).

However I want to use the system-wide tagging as well, but can't get that to work.
The tag field is shown when editing my own categories, but when I enter something and save the category I get an empty error message: `Save failed with the following error:`, and nothing behind the colon.

I have looked at the com_weblinks source for inspiration but can not figure out how to get tagging to work for my custom component categories.

**EDIT**
Digging in the code it seems that something is going wrong in `mapData()` of `JUcmContent`, but I am not familiar with that (deep) part of Joomla. Do I have to set up a mapping somewhere?

Comment: Are you able to edit the categories at all? Try changing the name of a category and see if that saves.

Comment: Yes I can edit the category, assign it to a parent and so on.

Comment: Well that takes out what I was thinking. I'm not at all familiar with the tag system yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, I have to set up a content type for my category in order for it to be taggable.

Info here: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension

Comment: I can only do that tomorrow, it says when I click.